# Should I build tensorflow_serving module every time using TFServing?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I installed and tried to serve Inception model with TFServing successfully. After that I try to apply it on my own model.
But when I looked into source code of the [example client](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py), it depend on `tensorflow_serving` module which was built by bazel. So here comes the problem, should I copy recursively whole tensorflow_serving directory beneath `serving/` to my repo and build it additionally, or just copy the file in bazel-bin directory. In my opinion, I would choose first way, however that means I would spend a lot of time building the module each time. Seems not to be a great way. Could someone offer me a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, [install Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install.html).

Then, clone the TF Serving repository:

```
mkdir $HOME/gitroot
cd $HOME/gitroot
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving tensorflow-serving
```

Finally, build the example app:

```
cd $HOME/gitroot/tensorflow-serving
bazel build --verbose_failures //tensorflow_serving/example:inception_client
```

Bazel takes care of building the dependencies, you don't need to copy anything.